# Search button not function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this search button in my page. But I don't have an idea why it is not working as in if I click it will re-direct to dashboard page.

```
MainApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
// Redirect any unmatched url
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("dashboard.html");
app.version = '1454574448';

$stateProvider.state('app', {
        url: "/app.html/:search?/:page?",
        templateUrl: 'views/app/app.html?_=' + app.version,
        controller: 'app'
    })
```

**This is my search button:**

```
<div class="input-group">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" ng-model="input.search" required ng-trim="true">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" tabindex="-1" ng-click="refresh()">Search</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**This is from the controller:**

```
$scope.page = ($routeParams.page) ? $scope.page = parseInt($routeParams.page) : 0;
$scope.input = {
    search: ($routeParams.search == undefined) ? '' : $routeParams.search,
};

$scope.refresh = function () {
    app.location.path('app/' + $scope.input.search + '/' + $scope.page);
};
```

Can someone help me to figure out the cause of error?

Comment: do you have a `refresh()` function to be triggered by the button click?

Comment: @TZHX yup. updated the code above

Answer (score 0):

Issue is that specific url and actual url is mismatching. So, that redirects to default page as that url doesn't exists.

Modify url in your state config

```
$stateProvider.state('app', {
    url: "/app/:search?/:page?",
    templateUrl: 'views/app/app.html?_=' + app.version,
    controller: 'app'
})
```

**EDIT**

Use [`$state.go`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state)  to change state

```
MainApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$state', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $state)
{
    // ...
    $scope.refresh = function () {
        $state.go('app' { 'search': $scope.input.search, 'page': $scope.page });
    };
    // ...
}
```

Comment: whats the different between your code and my code? i don't understand. could u provide me example?

Comment: @sue in your code url is `/app.html/:search?/:page?` and in mine url is `/app/:search?/:page?`

Comment: @sue and you are updating path to `'app/' + $scope.input.search + '/' + $scope.page`. So, you need to set the same in state config i.e. `/app/:search?/:page?`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109767/discussion-between-adnan-umer-and-sue).